# Asyncio from Python C-extension

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have a Python C-extension that gets data from a socket and processes it, during the processing it releases the GIL. Currently I use 2 Python threads that nicely intertwine due to the GIL-releasing, resulting in 90% load on 2 CPU cores.

How would I achieve the same in Python 3 asyncio? 
I cannot find the correct Python-C-API command to tell the event-loop that it can go and do something else.

Or put another way: if my extension releases the GIL, does this automatically mean that it will not block the execution of the next item available in the eventloop? E.g. will the next socket be read while my C-extension is processing the data of the first socket? This I cannot find anywhere. 
From what I understand this way I could get data from a number of sockets and put even more CPU cores to work.

Comment: As written, this isn't a very good question.  You need to sketch out how you'd like to see your extension interact with the event loop.  As you have described it, it doesn't sound like your extension should interact with the event loop at all.

Comment: If you can describe pseudocode describing the interactions you would like to have with your extension and the event loop, then it's probably possible to describe how to do that.

Comment: @SamHartman That might also be true. My question mostly is: if my extension releases the GIL, does this automatically mean that it will not block the execution of the next item available in the eventloop? 
E.g. will the next socket be read while my C-extension is processing the data of the first socket? This I cannot find anywhere.

Answer (score 5):

If your extension is called from inside the event loop, releasing the GIL will not cause the event loop to continue.

That is, say I do something like:

```
async def process():
    call_your_extension()

asyncio.get_event_loop.create_task(process())
```

then releasing the GIL in your extension will not cause the event loop to continue.  Your routine  is synchronous.

Instead, you could return or create an [awaitable](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/) of some kind and then do

```
async def process()
    await call_your_extension()
```

In this model, your extension would probably be a class with an `__await__` method.  Eventually, a `asyncio.futures.Future` would need to be generated.  The event loop would attach a done callback to that future, and when that done callback was called, the `process` could resume.
That's probably not going to be a good fit for something that wants to use multiple cores.  The event loop will only run in one thread.

You may be able to get some advantage by using `concurrent.futures` and generating a future that can run across threads.  You could then use `asyncio.ensure_future` to convert it into an `asyncio Future`.
However all this assumes that the event loop somehow benefits your extension.
That is only likely to be the case if you can move the reading from the socket out of your extension and into event-loop code.
Otherwise, your current design is probably ideal.
If you need to interoperate with an event loop model, take a look at `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_in_executor`